# Data values of uploaded images

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

There are a large number of classes ("df-table") on that link homepage. The first class was able to be entered into the Excel sheet, but not the second class ("df-table"), the third class ("df-table"), etc.

Various internet resources say it can be solved by using nth-of-type or using xpath, but the error keeps occurring.

I want the data values of the uploaded images.

```vb
Public Sub Jaemu()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim d As WebDriver, ws As Worksheet, URL As String
    
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("gemstone2")
        
    Dim http As New WinHttpRequest
    
    With d
        '.AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome"
            
        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        Dim JsonObject As Object
        
        Set html = New HTMLDocument
        URL = "https://globalmonitor.einfomax.co.kr/infomax_ds.html#/USA/1/1"
        .get URL, Raise:=False  ' set raise to false to avoid a timeout error
        d.FindElementByCss("[ng-click='openStockSearchPopup();']").Click
        d.FindElementByCss("[ng-enter='searchStockSearchPopup(true);']").SendKeys "GOOGL"
        d.FindElementByCss("[ng-click='searchStockSearchPopup(true);']").Click
        d.FindElementByCss("[class='slick-cell l1 r1 text-center clickable']").Click
        Cells(2, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss("[class='df-table']").Text
        Cells(3, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss(".table-contents[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.prospectData)'] > .df-table").Text

    End With
End Sub
```

Original OP error:

> runtime error 32.

Coding line.

```
Cells(3, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss("[class='df-table' class:nth-of-type(2)]").Text
```

New error following initial suggestion to use different CSS selector:

> Runtime error 7

Coding line.

```
Cells(3, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss(".table-contents[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.prospectData)'] > .df-table").Text
```

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur? Can you remove the commented out code which I assume is not part of the problem? Have you confirmed you are not working with an element inside an iframe/frame and/or this is not a timing issue?

Comment: problem error line is this. ...'Cells(3, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss("[class='df-table' class:nth-of-type(2)]").Text

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: uploaded now. 32 runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initial error (RTE32):**

The [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo class selector would go outside of the attribute selector closing `]` i.e. `"[class='df-table']:nth-of-type(2)"`, however this does not provide a match.

You can use:

```
.table-contents[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.prospectData)'] > .df-table
```

This returns a single match and is specific enough, and not reliant on a long selector list, that it is likely fairly stable. Based on experience.

If you had wanted to use `:nth-of-type()` you could have used it on a parent element and taken first match, but that is less stable and prone to breaking if html changes:

```
.contents-area:nth-of-type(5) .df-table
```

---

**Follow-up error (RTE7):**

The element needs to be scrolled into view.

A not ideal way is (your mileage may vary):

```
d.ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3);"
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
Activesheet.Cells(1,3) = d.FindElementByCss(".table-contents[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.prospectData)'] > .df-table").Text
```

There are better ways with inbuilt functions and custom JS which you can likely pull from the examples.xlsm by the author on GitHub. As I can only test with Python this was a quick and dirty test that worked.

---

You could avoid overhead of browser and use XHR to get a JSON response to then use a JSON parser with, as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim s As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://globalmonitor.einfomax.co.kr/facset/getKeyData", False
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        .send "{""param"":""NAS:AAPL""}"
        s = .responsetext
    End With

   Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm no expert, so I don't fully understand, so I'm asking the question again. Specifically, how should it be applied? For the second answer, I understood it as Cells(3, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss("[class='contents-area']:nth-of-type(5) .df-table").Text , the first answer The given is Cells(3, 1).Value = d.FindElementByCss("[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.prospectData)'] > .df-table").Text I tried to apply this, but an error occurs.

Comment: I searched the internet hard and went through a lot of trial and error, but I never learned to code professionally. I think the first sentence is more useful, please help me with how to apply it.

Comment: What is the error message? It would be applied as `d.FindElementByCss(".table-contents[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.prospectData)'] > .df-table").Text`

Comment: 7runtime error. nosuchelementerror. element not found for css=.talbe-contents[ng-if='IS_RT_STATE_SUCCESS(requeststate.pro:>.df-table

Comment: You first need to scroll to the element in order for it to be visible